# Checkbox apresenta erro no console quando muda o estado Checked

Tags: angular, angular-7

Estou fazendo uma veirficação no checkbox para fazer quando é falso e quando é true para mudar o estado `cheked` dele e está apresentando o seguinte erro:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current
>   value: 'ngIf: false'.

O codigo funciona mas se está dando esse erro acredito que possa ser melhorado e não exibir mais esse erro:

```
     <div class="form-group ml-1">
        <input id="filterImg" type="checkbox" class="check-filter-media" [checked]="gifCheck.checked === false" #imgCheck>
        <label for="filterImg" class="btn btn-filter-media">Imagem</label>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group ml-1">
         <input id="filterGif" type="checkbox" class="check-filter-media" [checked]="imgCheck.checked === false" #gifCheck>
         <label for="filterGif " class="btn btn-filter-media">GIF</label>
     </div>
   <app-component-1 *ngIf="imgCheck.checked === true"></app-component-1>
   <app-component-2 *ngIf="gifCheck.checked  === true "></app-component-2>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513421/ngif-expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu fiz assim, usando os dados que você passou. [angular-checkbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-teste?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)